# Is there a pure 'Pandas way' of coding equivalent to given 'outside Pandas' one?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

Answering a question **How to mark start/end of a series of non-null and non-0 values in a column of a Pandas DataFrame?** [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73777727/python-pandas-how-to-select-and-identfy-non-null-or-0-values-from-a-dataframe) on stackoverflow I have provided [a more general solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73778011/7711283) as the other answers. But while the other answers are coded 'the Pandas way' mine is coded in its core 'outside of Pandas'.

**What does 'the Pandas way' and 'outside of Pandas' exactly mean to me?** The Pandas way is in my eyes if there is no need to define own Python functions to achieve the result (this includes usage of lambda functions). If providing own functions is necessary to achieve the result I consider such approach as an 'outside Pandas' one.

In order to code also a pure Pandas solution I tried to modify [one of the other](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73777957/7711283) two provided pure Pandas solutions to make it more general too. Trying to translate the way I have done it using Pythons groupby to a pure 'Pandas way' of doing things I run into a problem because Pandas groupby I have used to group rows by two columns does not provide the same result as Python groupby does on a list of tuples with comparable values from the columns:

```
Python groupby: [((1, True), [(1, 1)]), ((1, False), [(1, 0), (1, 0), (1, 0)]), ((1, True), [(1, 1)]), ...]
Pandas groupby: { (1, 1.0):   [0, 4],    (1, nan):   [   1,      2,     3]    , #   in [0, 4] as 4  #  ...]
```

As can be seen from the above comparison while `Python groupby` groups only consecutive series of same values, so same values scattered over the sequence will be put in separate groups, `Pandas groupby` groups on the other hand also scattered values together making it useless as replacement for used Python groupby.

In this context my question is:

**Is there a pure 'Pandas way' to provide in this case same results as an 'outside Pandas' one does?**

*How would a pure 'Pandas way' look like for duplicating the same functionality as in following code example?* ( where 'A' marks start of a non-zero values series in the Value column within same series of Cycle values, 'B' marks the end and 'AB' is covering the case of only one value series within a Cycle ):

```
data = { 'Cycle': [1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3],
         'Value': [1,0,0,0,2,3,4,0,5,6,0,0,7,0,0]}  
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
from itertools import groupby
def getPOI(df):
    itrCV = zip(df.Cycle, df.Value)
    lstCV = list(zip(df.Cycle, df.Value)) # only for TEST purposes
    lstPOI = []
    print('Python groupby:', [ ((c, v), list(g)) for (c, v), g in groupby(lstCV, lambda cv: 
                          (cv[0], cv[1]!=0 and not pd.isnull(cv[1]))) ]
         ) # only for TEST purposes
    for (c, v), g in groupby(itrCV, lambda cv: 
                            (cv[0], not pd.isnull(cv[1]) and cv[1]!=0)):
        llg = sum(1 for item in g) # avoids creating a list
        if v is False: 
            lstPOI.extend([0]*llg)
        else: 
           lstPOI.extend(['A']+(llg-2)*[0]+['B'] if llg > 1 else ['AB'])
    return lstPOI
df["POI"] = getPOI(df)
print(df)
print('---')
print(df.POI.to_list())
```

Here the output created by the code above:

```
    Cycle  Value POI
0       1      1  AB
1       1      0   0
2       1      0   0
3       1      0   0
4       1      2  AB
5       2      3   A
6       2      4   B
7       2      0   0
8       2      5   A
9       2      6   B
10      3      0   0
11      3      0   0
12      3      7  AB
13      3      0   0
14      3      0   0
---
['AB', 0, 0, 0, 'AB', 'A', 'B', 0, 'A', 'B', 0, 0, 'AB', 0, 0]
```

Below the nice code provided by *Scott Boston* I consider to be a 'Pandas way' which fails to provide right results for series of scattered Value(s) within a Cycle:

```
mp = df.where(df!=0).groupby('Cycle')['Value'].agg([pd.Series.first_valid_index, 
                                            pd.Series.last_valid_index])
df.loc[mp['first_valid_index'], 'POI'] = 'A'
df.loc[mp['last_valid_index'], 'POI'] = 'B'
df['POI'] = df['POI'].fillna(0)
```

and for the sake of completeness also the code used to print a line used in the comparison between Python and Pandas groupby:

```
df.Value = df.Value.where(df.Value!=0).where(pd.isnull, 1)
print(  'Pandas groupby:',
        df.groupby(['Cycle','Value'], sort=False).groups
)
```

Comment: You are asking two different questrons here and the one in the title is extremely broad. Voting to close as requiring more focus. And _of course_ there are many features in Python which are not separately available as a vectorized Pandas function.

Comment: Edited the question to narrow it to the given example of code. By the way: numpy provides a method for making a Python function behave as vectorized. Does it Pandas too?

Comment: Question was closed in spite of focusing the question on an given example and existence of a nice and well done answer which could maybe be further shortened and improved, but with a closed question this will be prevented, robbing skilled pandas experts the chance to provide a better answer. For me a reason enough to re-open the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my take on your interesting question, using [shift](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html) and [mask](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html).

```py
# Setup
df["start"] = ""
df["stop"] = ""

# Find start and stop marks
df["start"] = (
    df["start"]
    .mask(
        ((df["Value"] != 0) & (df["Value"].shift(1).fillna(0) == 0))
        | (
            (df["Value"] != 0)
            & (df["Value"].shift(1).fillna(0) != 0)
            & (df["Cycle"].shift(1).fillna(method="bfill") != df["Cycle"])
        ),
        "A",
    )
)
df["stop"] = (
    df["stop"]
    .mask(
        ((df["Value"] != 0) & (df["Value"].shift(-1).fillna(0) == 0))
        | (
            (df["Value"] != 0)
            & (df["Value"].shift(-1).fillna(0) != 0)
            & (df["Cycle"].shift(-1).fillna(method="ffill") != df["Cycle"])
        ),
        "B",
    )
)

# Add POI and cleanup
df = df.assign(POI=df["start"] + df["stop"]).drop(columns=["start", "stop"])
```

```py
print(df)
# Output
    Cycle  Value POI
0       1      1  AB
1       1      0    
2       1      0    
3       1      0    
4       1      2  AB
5       2      3   A
6       2      4   B
7       2      0    
8       2      5   A
9       2      6   B
10      3      0    
11      3      0    
12      3      7  AB
13      3      0    
14      3      0
```

Comment: Thanks for the effort of answering my question. See the updated question for details about what I consider to be a 'Pandas way'. Your answer uses more (total of 5, with 4 lambda ones) 'outside Pandas' functions as mine (using one), so sorry, it's not what I was asking for, but ... an interesting approach anyway.

Comment: May you please explain how your code takes the values in the 'Cycle' column into consideration? I can't see in the code how and where it is done ...

Comment: Right. I've updated my answer with a `getPOI` function in which apply calls and lambdas are all removed. The "Cycle" column is taken into consideration by not applying `getPOI` to the whole dataframe, but to chunks (each corresponding to a cycle), and then concatenating them (this is done just after `getPOI` definition). Cheers.

Comment: Updated looks much better now. The next update step will be to get rid of the helper function. Is this function really necessary? Or can the loop over `i` be used instead, so that there is no need for a helper function at all? It seem to be so, but I am not really sure. Best would be to get rid of a list comprehension too as it is also 'outside Pandas' vectorized way of doing things. Is there a way to replace the loop by some vectorized method in Pandas?

Comment: Tough customer :) I've gotten rid of the helper function, list comprehension and concat call, see my updated answer. Cheers.

Comment: Wow! Very nice and well structured pure Pandas solution. Hope you  had fun and thanks for your effort to answer. This answer is sure putting not only my own but also some of the visitors Pandas skills to a next level. Chapeau :).